# Cloud e-mail client

Tags: web-apps, cloud-service, email-client

Do you know of any cloud software (website), that can act as a POP/SMTP email client?

I mean some tool like Outlook/Thunderbird/… that is entirely cloud/web based.

Gmail/Yahoo/… work with their own servers. I am looking for a cloud e-mail client that works with foreign POP/SMTP accounts.

Comment: Do you want to self-host this web app, or does it need to be hosted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are dozens online E-Mail clients available.

As I already stated in my comment to your question, many common Email Providers like Gmail allow you to embed foreign POP3, IMAP and SMTP Servers.

Also there are many dedicated online clients too.

A simple [search on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=imap%20online%20client) gives me several options.

1. [5 Ways to Check POP3/IMAP Accounts Online](http://www.nirmaltv.com/2007/08/06/5-ways-to-check-pop3imap-accounts-online/)
2. [Check POP3 And IMAP Email Accounts Via The Web](http://www.email-unlimited.com/stuff/check-email-via-web.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. That's indeed what I was looking for and I never knew Gmail could connect to foreign POP servers.

Comment: `Gmail allow you to embed foreign POP3, IMAP and SMTP Servers` at least 9 years ago [it wasn't supported](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/5739/133692). Is it supported now?

Answer (score 0):

[Roundcube](https://roundcube.net/) is an email web-client. It is self-hosted, i.e. you should install it oon your server.